# How to set the content-type of request header when using Fetch APi

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, request-headers, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am using npm 'isomorphic-fetch' to send requests. The problem I am experiencing is I am unable to set the content-type of the request header.

I set a content type of application/json , however the request header are being set to text/plain.

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

  sendRequest(url, method, body) {
    const options = {
      method: method,
      headers:{'content-type': 'application/json'},
      mode: 'no-cors'
    };

    options.body = JSON.stringify(body);

    return fetch(url, options);
  }
```

When I examine the request in my browser the content type is o :

```
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

Can anyone explain why I am unable to set this property?

Answer (score 85):

You need to create a fetch headers object.

```
sendRequest(url, method, body) {
    const options = {
        method: method,
        headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
        mode: 'no-cors'
    };

    options.body = JSON.stringify(body);

    return fetch(url, options);
}
```

Comment: this syntax works okay `headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },`

Comment: @RTS : this doesn’t seems to work if you include credentials.

Comment: This does not work when using useQuery (mutation) and using fetch call.

Answer (score 44):

I found the answer after reading the following article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers

> Guard
>
> Since headers can be sent in requests and received in responses, and have various limitations about what information can and should be mutable, headers objects have a guard property. This is not exposed to the Web, but it affects which mutation operations are allowed on the headers object.
>
> Possible guard values are:
>
> - `none`: default.
> - `request`: guard for a headers object obtained from a request (`Request.headers`).
> - `request-no-cors`: guard for a headers object obtained from a request created with `Request.mode` `no-cors`.
> - `response`: guard for a Headers obtained from a response (`Response.headers`).
> - `immutable`: Mostly used for ServiceWorkers; renders a headers object read-only.
>
> **Note**: You may not append or set a `request` guarded Headers’ `Content-Length` header. Similarly, inserting `Set-Cookie` into a response header is not allowed: ServiceWorkers are not allowed to set cookies via synthesized responses.

When the options mode property is set to no-cors the request header values are immutable.

Instead I set the mode property to cors.

Comment: yes but when you want no-cors? How do you say I want to send json data to an endpoint on another domain?

Comment: This the one that solved my problem

Answer (score 9):

You can not set some headers when you are using `mode: "no-cors"`.

So you can check Mozilla website:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

[image: screenshot of Mozilla code]

Comment: Thx for that hint. mode: "no-cors" was my problem.