# The variables never reach PHP from the FETCH API

Tags: php, fetch

I have 3 files (**HTML**,**JS** and **PHP**) in the **HTML** save de info in variable called **DatosPaciente** in JavaScript

```
function Tomar_DATOS(){            
  DatosPaciente={
    id:document.getElementById("paciente_id").value,
    fecha:document.getElementById("fecha").value
};}
```

Then i use a function called **Tiene_Cita_Hoy** inside of a **JS** file

```
Tiene_Cita_Hoy(DatosPaciente)
```

in the **JS** file i try to use the **Fetch API** to send info to the **PHP** file

```
function Tiene_Cita_Hoy(Datos){
console.log(Datos);//"{id: "8", fecha: "2020/09/03"}" here everything is fine
    fetch('tiene_cita.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: Datos
    })                           
        .then(res => res.json()) 
        .then(data => {                     
            console.log(data); //to see the result
        })
 }
```

then in a **PHP** file, then tried to receive the information via **POST**

```
  $VALOR_id_paciente=$_POST['id']; 
  $VALOR_fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
```

and then I assign those values ​​to a query

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='".$VALOR_id_paciente."' AND FECHA='".$VALOR_fecha."'";
echo json_encode($SQL);//just to see what information have
```

but the result is always: `SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='' AND FECHA=''`

apparently the information never reaches the PHP file

Comment: Some debugging details would help in *debugging* this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should send the parameters as a URL-encoded string.

```
function Tomar_DATOS(){            
  DatosPaciente = 'id=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("paciente_id").value) + '&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
}
```

Comment: throws me the following:  Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Comment: Sorry, that was a copying error. Of course it's supposed to be `document.getElementById`

Comment: that solved the error and now DatosPaciente: console.log(Datos);=id=8&fecha=2020%2F09%2F04, but apparently the information still does not get to the PHP file, because it returns the following: **SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='' AND FECHA=''**

Comment: Try sending the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: excuse my ignorance, where?

Comment: In the `headers:` option to `fetch()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156239/how-to-set-the-content-type-of-request-header-when-using-fetch-api

Comment: Finally it works **"SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='8' AND FECHA='2020/09/04'** Thank you

Comment: Now you need to learn to use prepared statements in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some proper way for this method to get working.
You need to make an object first, then pass it in 'for loop'. It will generate string like this for example (test=123&test_two=444)

```
async function catch_something(url, bodyContent = {test: 123, test_two: 444}){
let bodyContent_string = '';
if(bodyContent instanceof Object){
    for(const form_key of Object.keys(bodyContent)){
        if(form_key != Object.keys(bodyContent)[Object.keys(bodyContent).length - 1]){
            bodyContent_string += `${form_key}=${bodyContent[form_key]}&`;
        }else{
            bodyContent_string += `${form_key}=${bodyContent[form_key]}`;
        }
    }
}
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: bodyContent_string
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
if(!response.ok){
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
}
return response.json();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've passed a plain object to the `body` parameter, but `fetch` doesn't know what to do with that data type (so it converts it to the useless string `"[object Object]"`).

You should pass something that fetch knows how to convert into something supported by PHP instead.

e.g. a FormData object.

```
DatosPaciente = new FormData(document.getElementById("form_containing_your_inputs"));
```

Comment: throws me the following:   Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.

Comment: @Alejandro — Then the element with the ID “form_containing_your_inputs” isn’t a form that contains your inputs! Make sure it is one!

Comment: Sorry I'm relatively new to developing with javascript, I don't know how to do that, where can I find that information?