# Unable to access data from the request when using multipart/form-data in Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using the Fetch API in JavaScript. Up until now, I was using implicit set on the Content-Type header which is built in the browser. I.e: If the user sends JSON, the browser will set the Content-Type to `application/json`. If I send FormData, the browser will set the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data`.

This works well, but I am using an older version of a bundler that builds my web-app to an Android app which does not set the `content-type` header automatically.

For this, I need to explicitly define which content type I am using. However, when I do specify the content type explicitly, my request does not get processed correctly by the server - the server does not get the provided fields sent into the FormData object.

Here is how I send the request:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers()
myHeaders.append("content-type", "multipart/form-data")

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("email", "my.email@gmail.com");
formdata.append("password", "MySuperSecretPasswordOMG!");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

console.log(formData) // Here I see FormData {email: "my.email@gmail.com", password: "MySuperSecretPasswordOMG!" }

fetch("http://192.168.1.123:5000/users/auth/login", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

My server responds with error code 400 which I coded to return when any required fields are missing from the request:

```python
# Login validator created in Flask
data = request.form # email and password are NOT present in request.
required_keys = ["email", "password"]

if not self.validate(required_keys, data):
    return self._abort(400, "Incorrectly formatted request. Please make sure that all the required fields are entered.")

# Additional functions which are used above.
@staticmethod
def _abort(code, message):
    return jsonify({"msg": message, "code": code}), code

def validate(self, keys, data):
    for key in keys:
        if key not in data:
            return False
    return True
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a browser-related issue? Is this a backend/frontend related feature?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No. I do not want to change between the two. I was just providing that information in order to explain the implicit set of the `content-type` by the browsers.

Comment: Understood - I misread your question. Have you tried other methods of setting the headers, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38404295/519413

Comment: Isn't this basically the same? Weather I make an in-line instance of the `Headers` class or I instantiate it above, it is expected to work the same way. I will try it, however. After an hour of arguing with ChatGPT and not finding a solution, I am desperate.

Comment: In theory it should be, but I'm just suggesting we eliminate the easy things first

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: instead of wasting time with chatgpt, maybe good ol' debugging with chrome dev tools and curl could have helped...

Comment: How is your request looking alike if you check its whereabouts in the Network tab of your web-browser?

Comment: The headers are exactly the same, but the body is not forwarded by the client to the server via the request @LajosArpad

Comment: Missing the boundaries in the content type header.

Comment: @morganney How do I calculate them?

Comment: You just add them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

Comment: Does it have to be multipart/formdata? Can you use the normal urlencoded post?

Comment: @SalmanA has to be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @Dimitar fetch should add the boundary header and the payload. If it is not behaving as expected, you need to build the whole request body on your own.

Comment: @Dimitar is `formdata.getBoundary` a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to calculate the `boundary` yourself. Here how:

```js
// Generate a unique boundary string
const boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);

// Construct the body of the request
const requestBody = `--${boundary}\r\n` +
    `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n\r\n` +
    `my.email@gmail.com\r\n` +
    `--${boundary}\r\n` +
    `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\n` +
    `MySuperSecretPasswordOMG!\r\n` +
    `--${boundary}--`;

// Set the Content-Type header with the boundary
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundary}`
};

// Options for the fetch request
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: requestBody
};

fetch('http://192.168.1.123:5000/users/auth/login', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

In case you need `requestBody` to be constructed more dynamic:

```js
const data = {email: "my.email@gmail.com", password: "MySuperSecretPasswordOMG!"}

// Construct the body of the request
let requestBody = `--${boundary}\r\n`;

Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
  requestBody += `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="${key}"\r\n\r\n` +
      `${value}\r\n` + 
      `--${boundary}\r\n`;
});
```

Comment: My body is always dynamic. I have a createRequest function which is called by a createAsyncThunk function which is called by a createAction function which is called by a createHandler function. This is quite a complex tree. I wrote the code 2 and a half years ago when RTK-Query did not exist.

Comment: I edited my answer, added example incase you want requestBoyd to be more dynamic. Hope this help.